# Conver a list of features into a binary vector

Tags: pandas

I have several lists of features:

```
feat_lists = [
  ['f1','f2','f3'],
  ['f2','f3'],
  ['f2','f4']
]
```

And I'd like to arrange them in a way that each row represents a list (observation), and each column a feature. So the values are 1/0 or True/False, depending on the presence of the value in that list (observation).

For instance, for the example above, I'd like to have the following dataframe (shown as a table)

|  | f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | True | True | False |
| 2 | False | True | True | False |
| 3 | False | True | False | True |

I can figure out a way to do it, but I imagine there must be a better and more efficient way to do it in pandas

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) with casting to boolean by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(feat_lists),columns=mlb.classes_).astype(bool)
print (df)
      f1    f2     f3     f4
0   True  True   True  False
1  False  True   True  False
2  False  True  False   True
```

Comment: Great, thanks @jezrael